# is discord components removed?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i'm making a discord bot using `discord.py`
but i can't import discord_components like other people does
and i can't find much information about this module so i'm just wondering how can i use discord components now?

i tried doing `pip install --upgrade discord-components` in cmd
but it failed

The error message is below :

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement discord-components (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for discord-components

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> If you meet an error No matching distribution found for discord-components when installing, try updating the python version! (It must be upper than 3.6)

So, you need Python version 3.7 or higher.

Comment: i'm using the newest version of python right now and it shows the same error

Comment: @RickyRar Show me the output of this command `pip --version`